# Vbscript to gracefully close list of applications

Tags: vbscript

Following script is working but I would like to gracefully close it instead of terminate.

```
'Terminate processes

On Error Resume Next

' Define the list of applications by process
applist = "iexplore.exe|winword.exe|excel.exe|powerpnt.exe|calc.exe|wordpad.exe|mspaint.exe|notepad.exe|cmd.exe|chrome.exe"

'  Loop through the split list and close each process found running
For Each app In Split(appList, "|")
   set objProcs=GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process where Name= '" & app & "'")
   For Each process In objProcs
      process.Terminate ***(if I use .Quit, it does not run and does not give any error.)***
   Next
Next

wscript.quit()
```

Something similar to this.

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
objOutlook.Quit
```

Comment: There is no "graceful" option, you either kill the process or you don’t.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/959365/367122)